# How to put two webview one after another with wrap content?

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

I want to put top WebView for article and another for load disque comment, I tried following code but not working.
Article WebView hide if Disque WebView load before article.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#BDBDBD"
    tools:context="com.examkida.article.ArticleViewActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <WebView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/txtArticle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <WebView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/disqus"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The height of your second webview is `fill_parent` which would cause it to cover the first one, change it to `wrap_content`

Comment: thank you for replay, still same problem if comment load before article it only show comment not article .

Comment: you could try setting the webView heights to 0dp and then using `android:layout_weight="1"`in both of them.

is there any reason you couldnt have everything in one webview though

Answer (score 0):

```
I did this ........ like this way 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/txtArticle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/disqus"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtArticle"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```